# -Infinity added to database for NpgsqlParameter Timestamp field; expecting NULL

Tags: postgresql, null, timestamp

I'm inserting a record in my PostgresSQL table passing DBNull.Value for a timestamp without time zone field using a NpgsqlParameter as below:

```
ncmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(":EndDate", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp));
DateTime? dtval = sr.GetDateTime("EndDate");
ncmd.Parameters["EndDate"].IsNullable = true;
if (dtval.HasValue)
    ncmd.Parameters["EndDate"].Value = dtval;
else
    ncmd.Parameters["EndDate"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

When I try to select only those records with null values for the field I use "Select * From "EVAL" Where "EndDate" IS NULL" but nothing is returned. When I read the table data in the pgAdmin I see the value "-infinity" in the field. 
Please, could somebody tell me how to pass null values for a NpgsqlParameter?

Thanks in advance,

Danilo da Silva

Comment: Take a look ate the table definition. -infinity for a start_date and +infinity for an end_date are sane and useful default values (and less messy than a nullable timestamp field)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've found my error. When I read the data to be inserted from a datareader, I was getting a default value for the DateTime field when it is null and so I was inserting default(DateTime) not DBNull.Value. Now I'm testing dtval.HasValue && dtval != default(DateTime) and all goes right. Thanks.